# Angularjs 1.5 localstorage getting overwrite when i open application in new tab with some other credentials

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs 1.5 I have used local storage to store session related information.
But when I open new tab with some other credentials, initial information is getting erased and getting replaced by the new one, is there any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, What you are doing is replacing the same key with new data that is why it is getting replaced. What you should be doing is create new 'Key' for each session.

Example

```
//localStorage.setItem('key', 'value' )
//What you should do is for each login user create a new key

//sessionId can be any id you want for new session, this way you won't overwrite the previous session data
  localStorage.setItem(sessionId, loginSessionData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code sample it's hard to tell what is going on, but i guess when the app starts you set some value to localstorage, so each time you open a new tab you set it again and override the previous value.

All you need to do is check if the value exists in localstorage and if it does do nothing:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('myItem')){
      localStorage.setItem('myItem', myValue));
}
```